# Using ARP protocol with OpenVPN routed (TUN) tunnel

Tags: home-networking, openvpn, tunnel, tomato, arp

I've configured network shown in the following diagram:

[image]

ROT1 is Tomato-based router. It has BR0 bridged network interface for all the clients within internal network with subnet 192.168.1.0/24. One of the clients is a NAS device (NAS01) which provides some basic services like ownCloud and SMB server. Both LAP01 and MOB01 clients are able to see NAS01 and use its services. ROT1 has also two VPNs configured: TAP0 is an OpenVPN bridged tunnel which is bridged with BR0, that's why client LAP04 receives IP address from DHCP server within subnet 192.168.1.0/24. This client is also able to ping NAS01 device within internal subnet. Router ROT01 is running `arpwake` program to automatically wake up NAS01 with Magic Packet when the host is requested by some other client in the network with ARP request (who-has). You can find the description of the application and links for its source code [here](http://taras.glek.net/blog/2013/02/17/router-assisted-automatic-wake-on-lan-plus-suspend/). `arpwake` application is listening on BR0 for ARP request containing MAC address of NAS01 and automatically sends Magic Packet if one of the clients within the network asks for it.
The problem is that I'm trying to set up routed VPN tunnel also with OpenVPN that will allow me to use `arpwake` application in order to automatically wake NAS01 when one of the clients from TUN0 network will ask for it. If NAS01 is up I can ping it and use all the services, but if it's down I cannot wake it up with `arpwake` application, because there are no ARP requests on that interface (TUN0) - I've already checked that with tcpdump on the router. I've also tried to use Proxy ARP with command `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/proxy_arp` but still it doesn't work.

Here's the configuration of the router:

**Routes**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.200.2   *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 vlan2
192.168.200.0   192.168.200.2   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vlan2
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vlan2
```

**iptables** (output of `iptables-save` concerning only TUN0)

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.8 on Sun Aug 28 12:08:23 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [50195:5904352]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [409:28145]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4413:306096]
-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Aug 28 12:08:23 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.8 on Sun Aug 28 12:08:23 2016
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1628436:1350223724]
:INPUT ACCEPT [43707:3160699]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [1563428:1344198921]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [13790:1556262]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1576178:1345632445]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Aug 28 12:08:23 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.8 on Sun Aug 28 12:08:23 2016
*filter
:INPUT DROP [10689:641141]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [19:1151]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [13539:1531250]
-A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Aug 28 12:08:23 2016
```

**TUN0 OpenVPN config** (security related options removed)

```
local [IP_address]
port [PORT]
proto udp
dev tun
server 192.168.200.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1"
```

**ifconfig for TUN0 interface** (by default OpenVPN brings this interface up with NOARP option, but even if I turn this back on with command `ifconfig tun0 arp` it does not solve my problem).

```
tun0       Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
           inet addr:192.168.200.1  P-t-P:192.168.200.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
           UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:311 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
           RX bytes:21166 (20.6 KiB)  TX bytes:3486 (3.4 KiB)
```

My question is: how to make this TUN0 interface to start working with ARP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-IP traffic is not forwarded over Layer-3 (*tun*) interfaces, that's the whole beauty of it: you save on broadcast traffic and on ethernet headers. You can read about all of this on [the OpenVPN wiki](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting).

I am not sure I understand how *arpwake* works, the Web page you linked to is more of a ramble than a wiki. But you may try adding this firewall rule,

```
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This rewrites all source IP addresses, in the packet headers, with the router IP address. I do not know whether this will trigger *arpwake*, but you may try.

**EDIT**:

I have thought of a workaround, which does not use *arpwake*. Add the following *iptables* rule,

```
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0  -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24 -d 192.168.1.4/32 -m state --state NEW -m state ! --state ESTABLISHED -j LOG --log-prefix "NEW_CONN_ATTEMPT"
```

where *xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24* is VPN tunnel's network. Now setup an executable script, running under *sudo*, with the following content:

```
tail -f /var/log/firewall.log | awk '/NEW_CONN_ATTEMPT/ {system("/usr/local/bin/myscript")}'
```

where */usr/local/bin/myscript* is a script that sends the magic packet to the NAS. It should work.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this does not solve the problem, still there are no ARP requests, but I guess this is the specific of tun interface.

Comment: @KrzysztofJakóbczyk Can you  empty the arp cache (*ip neigh flush dev br0*) , then try connecting to the NAS via tun0? I do not understand why this does not work. I thought you would run *arpwake* on the ROT1 server, and that would make an ARP request for 192.168.1.4, which should be captured by *arpwake* and converted to a WOL magic packet. Can you also check that the ARP request from ROT1 is actually sent?

Comment: I've done what you've suggested but still with no luck. _arpwake_ in general is network sniffing tool that is looking for ARP requests comming from clients to ROT1 router. If it finds such request for MAC address passed trough command line option it will automatically send WOL packet to broadcast address of network in which the host resides (in general it always sends WOL to .255 of each subnet what doesn't have to be always the broadcast address, but it is in my case). If I check with _tcpdump -i tun0_ what happens on TUN0 interface I can only see IP transmissions, no ARP's.

Comment: Also ICMP is working, but not ARP, however this is related, according to your answer, to TUN interfaces specific: they only work with IP-related traffic, that's why the TUN0 interface is being brought up with NOARP option and even turning it on does not allow me to see ARP traffic. If I use TAP interface instead of TUN the ARP requests are being captured with _tcpdump -i br0_ and this is when _arpwake_ fires up booting NAS device with WOL.

Comment: @KrzysztofJakóbczyk Ok, but what I am getting at is: why does not *arpwake* activate itself when the **router** sends out an ARP packet for the NAS? I was hoping *arpwake* would not be triggered only by outside ARP requests, but also the outer's itself. See wham I am hinting at?

Comment: @KrzysztofJakóbczyk Pls read my Edit, I may have found you a workaround, not quite a solution.

Comment: Yes, I now got your point, but I think that I also got an answer: _arpwake_ is bound to specific network interface, in this case to TUN0 so my question is on which NIC should I look for such ARP requests raised by the router itself? On LO?

Comment: Also I've read your edit and I think this will work but I wanted to avoid iptables logging. With this solution I would need to check the contents of the log file with crown job and the NAS device could be waken up only after each execution of such job, i.e. 1 min the shortest.

Comment: @KrzysztofJakóbczyk No, you should search for ARP queries  on *br0*. As for the *cron* job, you equivocate. The *cron* job can be used to start the *tail -f...* job, once and for all at boot. Reading the *log* file will occur in **real** time.

Comment: There are no ARP requests on _br0_ raised from _tun0_. I'm sure about it, because on ROT1 there are two instances of _arpwake_ running, one on _br0_ and another listening on _tun0_. I need the other instance to wake NAS device with queries coming from local network. As for the _cron_ job I think that your solution will suit my needs even though I was hoping to make _tun0_ to send ARP requests.